# Why is this question massively down-voted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

- [What is the purpose of variable sz in this routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52145081/what-is-the-purpose-of-variable-sz-in-this-routine)

I think, this is one kind of abuse of people's rights.

> The following routine subtract the mean value from the image making it
>   sharper.
>
> ```
> function pad = erase_mean(im, sz)    
>     im = double(im);
>
>     pad = floor(sz/2);
>     [m,n,o] = size(im);
>
>     mask = ones(sz,sz);
>
>     for q=1:o       
>         im(:,:,q)=double(im(:,:,q))-conv2(double(im(:,:,q)),mask,'same')./sz^2;
>
>         mx=max(max(im(1+pad*2:m-pad*2,1+pad*2:n-pad*2,q)));
>
>         im(:,:,q)=(im(:,:,q)./mx).*255;        
>     end;
>
>     mx = max(max(im(1+pad*2:m-pad*2,1+pad*2:n-pad*2,q)));
>     im = uint8((im./mx(1)).*255);
>     pad = im(1+pad*2:m-pad*2,1+pad*2:n-pad*2,:);
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> - What is the purpose of variable sz in this routine?
> - pad is used as an integer and a matrix at the same time?

- Is it illegal to ask for code explanation?
- What more explanation could I provide? If I could provide more explanation, why would I post the question in the 1st place?

***Accepted answer***

Even the answer is being down-voted.

> If `sz` is an scalar value, it defines the dimensions of the square
>   matrix `mask`. It's more interesting to see what `mask` does,
>   substract the mean value to catch the extreme values of the image, as
>   explained in the kmdreko's answer.

If this question was not answerable, how could he answer and how could I accept the answer?

Comment: Note that no one claimed that "the question is not answerable". The tooltip for the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: "Abuse of people's rights"? Really? Come on...

Comment: What "rights" would those be?

Comment: see also: [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/839601)

Comment: I was the answerer to that question and OP changed the question so it now does not answer the new question. This is a reason that discourages me to answer questions, as it now seems pointless the time I devoted to read and provide an answer to what OP asked. How do mods proceed in these cases?

Comment: @mrbolichi a mod, or even a sufficiently-privileged user such as myself, could roll it back.  I won't do it here because it's matlab and, lacking the technical skills, I would not vote/rollback or otherwise touch it.  The best user to judge on possible rollbacks would be a high-rep matlab user.  Not sure how you would go about finding one who could look at it:(

Answer (score 31):

> What more explanation could I provide? If I could provide more
>   explanation, why would I post the question in the 1st place?

When you write your next question, consider SO like you would an encyclopedia.

If an encyclopedic article on Matlab was entitled, `What is the purpose of variable sz in this routine?` would it have any significance? Well, clearly not.

The reason why I emphasize the title is it pinpoints the issue with the question itself. It is **so localized** that it will have no use for anyone else. There are **millions** of such functions in the public domain. Does each variable in each function need an independent explanation?

Of course, the people at SO are happy to help if they see **evidence** of you trying to work it out for yourself. One way you can achieve this is explain what you *currently* understand about the function and why the use of a particular variable seems questionable.

But that's not what you've done. You've provided a code dump and a highly localized question.